# Error al leer id de un botón con CommandArgument ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Tengo un gridview paginado con una lista de clientes, en cada fila se genera dinamicamente para cada una de estas filas un botón "Imprimir" que al darle click me muestra un PDF con los datos del cliente seleccionado usando como señalador el índice del botón.
El problema lo tengo cuando hago click en alguna fila de las páginas 2 en adelante, mientras seleccione un cliente de la primer página funciona perfecto, pero al pasar a la 2da página u otra más adelante no lee el indice del botón.
El índice lo leo de esta manera:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
```

Dejo el código aspx del gridview.

```
<div id="divGrilla" runat="server" style="overflow: auto; min-height: 75px; margin-top: 0.2px;">
            <asp:GridView ID="gvClientes" Width="100%" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                DataKeyNames="ID"
                CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None"
                CssClass="Gridview"
                HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridviewHeader"
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="GridViewAlternate"
                AllowPaging="True" EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True" OnPageIndexChanging="gvClientes_PageIndexChanging"
                AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="gvClientes_Sorting" OnRowDataBound="gvClientes_RowDataBound"
                OnRowEditing="gvClientes_RowEdit" OnRowDeleting="gvClientes_RowDelete">
                <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternate" />
                <Columns>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Width="37px" Wrap="False" />
                        <HeaderStyle Width="37px" Wrap="False" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="37px" Wrap="False" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderImageUrl="~/Imagenes/impresión.png">
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <asp:Button ID="Imprimir" Text="Imprimir" runat="server" OnClick="gvClientes_ImprimirFichaCliente" CommandArgument="<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>" CommandName="Imprimir" />


                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>


                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblTipoPersona %>" DataField="tipoPersonaDescripcion" SortExpression="tipoPersonaDescripcion" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblNombre %>" SortExpression="nombre">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 150px"><%# Eval("nombre")%></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblApellido %>" SortExpression="apellido">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 150px"><%# Eval("apellido")%></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblEstado %>" DataField="idestado" SortExpression="idestado" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblTipoDoc %>" DataField="tipoDocDescripcion" SortExpression="tipoDocDescripcion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblNroDoc %>" DataField="nroDocumento"
                        SortExpression="nroDocumento">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblCuitCuilCdi %>" DataField="cuit_cuil_cdi"
                        SortExpression="cuit_cuil_cdi">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, msgCondicionIVA %>" DataField="condicioniva_descripcion"
                        SortExpression="condicioniva_descripcion"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblSexo %>" DataField="sexo"
                        SortExpression="sexo"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblFechaNac %>" DataField="nacimiento_fecha"
                        SortExpression="nacimiento_fecha" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblLugarNacimiento %>" DataField="lugar_nacimiento"
                        SortExpression="lugar_nacimiento"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblNacionalidad %>" DataField="nacionalidad"
                        SortExpression="nacionalidad"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblEstadoCivil %>" DataField="estado_civil_descripcion"
                        SortExpression="estado_civil_descripcion"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblOcupacion %>" SortExpression="ocupacionDescripcion">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 200px"><%# Eval("ocupacionDescripcion")%></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblFechaInscripcion %>" DataField="inscripcion_fecha"
                        SortExpression="inscripcion_fecha" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"></asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblInscripcion %>" DataField="inscripcion_numero"
                        SortExpression="inscripcion_numero">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblActividadPrincipal %>" SortExpression="actividad_principal">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 100px"><%# Eval("actividad_principal")%></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblDireccion %>" SortExpression="direccion">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div style="width: 150px"><%# Eval("direccion")%></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblPiso %>" DataField="piso" SortExpression="piso">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblDepartamento %>" DataField="dto" SortExpression="dto" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblPais %>" DataField="paisDescripcion" SortExpression="paisDescripcion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblProvincia %>" DataField="provinciaDescripcion" SortExpression="provinciaDescripcion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblLocalidad %>" DataField="localidadDescripcion" SortExpression="localidadDescripcion" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblTelefono %>" DataField="telefono" SortExpression="telefono">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblCelular %>" DataField="celular" SortExpression="celular">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblEmail %>" SortExpression="email">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="wraptexto" style="width: 200px"><%# Eval("email")%></div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblUsuarioModif %>" DataField="usuarioModifNombre" SortExpression="usuarioModifNombre" />
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:gd, lblFecModif %>" DataField="fecModif" SortExpression="fecModif" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:BoundField>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Id" DataField="ID" SortExpression="Id" />
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblNoHayDatos" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridviewHeader" />
                <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSortDirection" runat="server" Value="ASC" />
        </div>
```

El aspx.cs:

```
protected void gvClientes_ImprimirFichaCliente(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (((Button)sender).CommandName.ToUpper() == "IMPRIMIR")
            {
                ClienteDTO clienteDTO = new ClienteDTO();
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument); //--> Acá es donde leo el Indice y al pasar a la 2da página lanza la excepción.
                this.Cliente_Selected = int.Parse(gvClientes.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString()); //--> Me traigo los datos de la fila según el indice del botón que clickeé.
                NegClientes negClientes = new NegClientes();
                clienteDTO = negClientes.leer_cliente_id(new ClienteDTO() { ID = this.Cliente_Selected }); //--> StoredProcedure que busca en mi DB y trae al cliente seleccionado

                string DirecTemp = "~/logs/temp/";
                string archivo = "FichaCliente (" + clienteDTO.ID.ToString() + ") " + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-") + ".pdf";

                // Creamos el documento con el tamaño de página tradicional
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);   // Indicamos donde vamos a guardar el documento
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer = iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath(DirecTemp) + archivo, FileMode.Create)); 
          // Acá sigue todo el código del documento PDF donde muestro los datos
            }  
      }
```

Aclaración: No puedo ver por dentro qué está trayendo el código porque al debuggear me dice que

> "no se puede evaluar la expresión porque el código del método actual
>   está optimizado"

**Actualización**
La excepción que lanza es de fuera de indice.
El gridview está paginado cada 10 filas, ¿podría ser que si le paso un indice mayor a 9 es cuando se produce esta excepción?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Publico la solución que encontré.
El error estaba en que no me devolvía el indice de la fila actual en el gridView, lo único que tuve que hacer fue cambiar el CommandArgument a:

```
CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex %>"
```

Esto me devuelve el indice de la fila que cada vez que cambie de página siempre debe ser de 0 a 9 (en mi caso, ya que como dije antes el gridview está paginado cada 10 filas).
Luego en el codebehind hago:

```
if (((Button)sender).CommandName.ToUpper() == "IMPRIMIR")
            {
                ClienteDTO clienteDTO = new ClienteDTO();
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)sender).CommandArgument);
                this.Cliente_Selected = int.Parse(gvClientes.DataKeys[index].Values[0].ToString());
                NegClientes negClientes = new NegClientes();
                clienteDTO = negClientes.leer_cliente_id(new ClienteDTO() { ID = this.Cliente_Selected });  
             }
// Luego el resto del código.
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que necesitas es el ID del cliente, podes usar eso en el CommandArgument

```
CommandArgument="<%# Eval("ID") %>" <-- Si es que se llama ID
```

Por otro lado, en lugar de utilizar el Click del boton, es más claro usar el [RowCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) de la GridView

```
void gvClientes_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   this.Cliente_Selected = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
   NegClientes negClientes = new NegClientes();
   clienteDTO = negClientes.leer_cliente_id(new ClienteDTO() { ID = this.Cliente_Selected }); 
}
```

Comment: Lo que necesitaba en sí es el número de fila, de esta manera ya lo había probado pero no resultó. El numero de fila que en cada página debía ser entre 0 y 9 dependiendo de la fila que seleccione y me devolvia el numero de fila total, por ejemplo en la pag 5 tenía las filas 50 a 59 en vez de 0 a 9. Ya publiqué de qué manera lo resolví. Gracias por el aporte.